# changing column names of a data frame by changing values - R

Tags: r, dataframe

Let I have the below data frame.

```
df.open<-c(1,4,5)
df.close<-c(2,8,3)

df<-data.frame(df.open, df.close)



> df
  df.open df.close
1       1        2
2       4        8
3       5        3
```

I wanto change column names which includes "open" with "a" and column names which includes "close" with "b":

Namely I want to obtain the below data frame:

```
  a b
1 1 2
2 4 8
3 5 3
```

I have a lot of such data frames. The pre values(here it is "df.") are changing but "open" and "close" are fix.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can create a function for reuse

```
f1 <- function(dat) {
     names(dat)[grep('open$', names(dat))] <- 'a'
      names(dat)[grep('close$', names(dat))] <- 'b'
     dat
}
```

and apply on the data

```
df <- f1(df)
```

-output

```
df
  a b
1 1 2
2 4 8
3 5 3
```

---

if these datasets are in a `list`

```
lst1 <- list(df, df)
lst1 <- lapply(lst1, f1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to dear @akrun's insightful suggestion as always we can do it in one go. So we create character vectors in `pattern` and `replacement` arguments of `str_replace` to be able to carry out both operations at once. We can assign character vector of either length one or more to each one of them. In case of the latter the length of both vectors should correspond. More to the point as the documentation says:

> References of the form \1, \2, etc will be replaced with the contents
> of the respective matched group (created by ())

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  rename_with(~ str_replace(., c(".*\\.open", ".*\\.close"), c("a", "b"))) 

  a b
1 1 2
2 4 8
3 5 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Another base R option using `gsub` + `match` + `setNames`

```
setNames(
  df,
  c("a", "b")[match(
    gsub("[^open|close]", "", names(df)),
    c("open", "close")
  )]
)
```

gives

```
  a b
1 1 2
2 4 8
3 5 3
```